# The gender of 子

Tags: kanji, meaning, gender

Is 子 ever used to refer to a boy, or is it always used for girls? Is 悪い子 used only for girls?

Comment: This question probably comes from noticing how common '-ko' is as an ending for girls' names.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Yes, `悪い子` can be used for boys.](http://eow.alc.co.jp/%E6%82%AA%E3%81%84%E5%AD%90/UTF-8/)

`子` means "child", and it can refer to girls or boys depending on the context.